# Stash Pull Request Builder plugin for Jenkins custom variables in comments

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, bitbucket-server

I have the Stash pull request builder plugin working great in Jenkins, it see's a pull request and kicks off the Jenkins job which runs some tests and puts a generic comment on the pull request saying pass or fail.

The problem I'm having is when the plugin comments back to the pull request I'd like to use a variable I create in the post build section, I've tried creating the variable as an environment variable but it seems the comments part of the plugin can only see the built in Jenkins variables like ${BUILD_NUMBER} anything else just prints out the name directly.

I've had a look at envinject, but I'm not sure how to set a variable from it in the post build section, or even if the variables it creates would be seen by the Pull Request Builder Plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a quick test with my Jenkins/Stash platform.

I have a job using this custom variable:

[image]

I've added a post-build step to publish a custom comment:

[image]

We can see that my SCM_REVISION environment variable is displayed in Stash:

[image]

I hope it helped :)

Comment: That was helpful, thanks. I ended up modifying it slightly to load the variables from a propertiesfile, that a process in the build step had written to.